# How can I target a specific class to toggle views to user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on a my comments button, I want to show them the comments for that post. As of now, on page load, these comments are hidden by a class.

I can't figure out how to hide the comments from showing and then when a user clicks on a specific comments button, only showing those comments for a post.

Right now i display all the comments for each post.

I have a post._id that i can use to target a specific set of comments but i am unsure how to use that piece of data. Any thoughts?

Jade File

```
.fullPostContainer
            each post in posts
                .media.white.paddingBoxForPost
                    .media-left.media-middle
                        a.removeTextDeco(href=post.link,   target='_blank')
                            img.media-object(src=post.img, alt='facebook logo')

                    .media-body
                        a.removeTextDeco(href=post.link, target='_blank')
                            div#mainTitlePost.media-heading.postTitleFont= post.title
                            div#mainShortDesc.descriptionFont= post.description
                        //form.formSub
                        //    label(for='upvote')
                        button.upvoteClick.btn.btn-lg.btnColor(value= post._id)
                            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-fire= post.upvote
                        button.btn.commentsInit.btn-lg.btnColor(value= post._id)
                            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment
                .commentsForTheWin.hideOnLoad
                        p this is some text
                        span
```

JS file

```
$(function () {

$('.commentsInit').click(function () {


    // grabs value of button which is post._id
    // var uniCommID = $(this).attr("value");


    $('.hideOnLoad').toggle("slow");


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/comments"
    }).success(function (users) {

        var a = JSON.stringify(users);
        $('.commentsForTheWin span').text("Comments but not really for " + a);

    })

})

});
```

I am getting exactly what I want from my DB for now but i am just having the hardest time figuring out how to target specific classes (or if that is even possible).

Comment: Need HTML, it's not very clear what and where needs hiding and showing.

Comment: Or clear what the data response looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery `.closest()` to traverse up the tree from your `.commentsInit` button, stored a reference to the parent `.paddingBoxForPost` in a variable and used that to target relevant elements.

```
$(function() {
  $('.commentsInit').click(function() {

    // grabs value of button which is post._id
    // var uniCommID = $(this).attr("value");

    var $post = $(this).closest('.paddingBoxForPost');

    $post.find('.hideOnLoad').toggle("slow");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/api/comments"
      }).success(function(users) {
        var a = JSON.stringify(users);
        $post.find('.commentsForTheWin span').text("Comments but not really for " + a);
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: I could not seem to get this work. I am now trying some different traversing methods but can't seem to get them to work either

Comment: @AndrewLittle Going to need more information than that to help, sorry! Blind as a bat without being able to see an example. Can you set up a JSFiddle?